Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a small abelian category. Then there is a ring $R$ and an exact, full, and faithful functor $\mathcal{C} \to R$-mod
Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a small abelian category. Then there is a ring $R$ and an exact, full, and faithful functor $\mathcal{C} \to R$-mod.
The above statement is from a lecture note, and I am having hard time proving it. I think this may be related to the Gabriel-Popescu theorem but I am not sure how this would work, especially since we are just looking at a small abelian category and not a Grothiendick category. For the context, we have been studying the Hom functor in an abelian category. I am aware of the Snake lemma, but I am not sure if this will be useful here.

The statement is Freyd-Mitchell's embedding theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mitchell's_embedding_theorem

In particular, from what it sounds like you know so far it would be very challenging to prove this on your own, and the author of the lecture notes is certainly not intending you to do so.
